# Very bad rendering in Cycle Viewport

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I am new in this community and also as Blender user.
I am working with Blender 2.91.
I have probably typed by mistake on a shortcut or changed a setting, ... I have now a very bad rendering result in the Cycles viewport.  This is only happening in one of my Blender files, the others are OK.
The final rendering is also fine.  I tried several materials, ... same bad result.
Have anybody an idea of what I did wrong and how I could solve this problem?
Many thanks in advance,
Jean
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, please edit your question and share screenshots of your render settings.

Comment: Hello Martynas. Thank you for your response. I have added the render settings. I hope this will help.

Comment: What GPU are you using?

Comment: Hello Nascent, I have a GEforce GTX 1080. ... But as the final rendering is fine, I don't think it is the problem.